# Unable to start Zookeeper server - Kafka Setup getting The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: windows, apache-zookeeper

[this is the picture for more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EMyT.png) I am trying to make do Kafka setup and facing issue with zookeeper server starting

the command which I am using is:

`.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties`

the error I am getting is.

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Zookeeper is no longer required to use Kafka. See latest docs
2. Kafka is not end-to-end tested in Windows. You'll have better luck using WSL2 or Docker

Comment: now it is working as expected. I have updated the folder name from kafka_2.12-3.5.0 to Kafka may be in windows naming convention issue because of that one i got an issue now it's resolved.  :)

Comment: I don't know where the underscores, periods, or dashes would cause start script issues, but glad you sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

now it is working as expected. I have updated the folder name from kafka_2.12-3.5.0 to Kafka may be in windows naming convention issue because of that one I got an issue now it's resolved. :)